# Adicionar valor do DropDownList ao banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Queria colocar um `dropdownlist` na minha view onde o valor da List dele fosse para o banco de dados, porém sei somente como adicionar valores ao `DropDownlist` com dados de uma tabela, queria fazer um `DropDownlist` com três valores sem ter que cria uma tabela nova e coloca na minha View Razor.

Aqui está um exemplo de como faço nas minhas views:

```
    @model BlogWeb.ViewsModels.VisitaModel

@Html.ValidationMessage("DtIntegracao.Invalido")

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.Nome)
@Html.LabelFor(v => v.Nome, "Nome:")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Nome)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.Rg)
@Html.LabelFor(v => v.Rg, "Rg:")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Rg)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.DtIntegracao)
@Html.LabelFor(v => v.DtIntegracao, "Data Integração:")
@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.DtIntegracao, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { Type = "date" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.ResponsavelId)
@Html.LabelFor(v => v.ResponsavelId, "Responsavel Entrada:")
@Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.ResponsavelId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Usuarios, "Id", "Nome"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Duas opções de serem feitas é manual ou com o `enum`, abaixo segue exemplo das duas formas

**Manual:**

Crie um `select`

```
<select id="Info" name="Info">
    <option value="0">Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Info 1</option>
    <option value="2">Info 1</option>
    <option value="3">Info 1</option>
</select>
```

No seu model crie uma propriedade com o mesmo `name` do select

```
public class VisitaModel
{
    public int Info { get; set; }
}
```

Pronto, ao realizar um `post` a propriedade Info terá o valor selecionado.

**Enum:**

Crie um `enum`, o atributo `Display` é usado para definir qual texto será exibido

```
public enum MeuEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "Info 1")]
    Info1 = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Info 2")]
    Info2 = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Info 3")]
    Info3 = 4
}
```

No seu model crie uma propriedade com o tipo do `enum`

```
public class VisitaModel
{
    public MeuEnum MeuEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Na sua view, use o *helper* `EnumDropDownListFor`

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.MeuEnum, "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Pronto, ao realizar um `post` a propriedade MeuEnum terá o valor selecionado.